# application for access

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

If I want to apply for access to files on network in office, Can I say:

> please help **open access to** the document folder , address//……,

I mean, is the phrase "open access to something" is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term usually used in operating systems for the ability to access files is **permission**.  So I might write this:

> Can you please help me get permission to access the document folder [address]?

Depending on the permission structure in place, you might also have to specify either **read permission** (if you just want to view the documents) or **read/write permission** (if you want to be able to modify the documents).